# configuring kernel source for manual module compilation

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules

I need to compile an xpad module from source, system is debian wheezy, the platform is ci20. I cannot locate linux headers-3.0.8-(...) anywhere (not on the system, not on the web, not in  official repositories).

I do have kernel source code available but I am not sure how to make use of it. When I try to use the module-assistant with the -k /path/to/kernel/sourcecode option it complains that it is 'not configured', the kernel source code isn't. When I tried to just 'make' it it fails because I am missing linux headers. Since I cannot find the linux headers I am not sure how to proceed. Is there another way to get what I need or to use this source code in any way to build this module?

Does anyone have any advice for me? Is there any article or resource I could reach to that would explain this issue for me so I get the idea what to do next or what to try?

```
apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://deb.flowworld.com/ flowsdk/main mipsel Packages
     release o=. flowsdk,n=flowsdk,l=. flowsdk,c=main
     origin deb.flowworld.com
 500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports/main mipsel Packages
     release v=,o=Debian Backports,a=wheezy-backports,n=wheezy--backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin http.debian.net
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free mipsel Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/contrib mipsel Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main mipsel Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/non-free mipsel Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/contrib mipsel Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main mipsel Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/non-free mipsel Packages
     release v=7.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/contrib mipsel Packages
     release v=7.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main mipsel Packages
     release v=7.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
Pinned packages:

apt-cache search linux-header
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-4kc-malta - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-4kc-malta
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-5kc-malta - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-5kc-malta
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all-mipsel - All header files for Linux 3.2 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common - Common header files for Linux 3.2.0-4
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-loongson-2f - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-loongson-2f
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-r5k-cobalt - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-r5k-cobalt
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-sb1-bcm91250a - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-sb1-bcm91250a
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-sb1a-bcm91480b - Header files for Linux 3.2.0-4-sb1a-bcm91480b
linux-headers-2.6-4kc-malta - Header files for Linux 4kc-malta configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-5kc-malta - Header files for Linux 5kc-malta configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-loongson-2f - Header files for Linux loongson-2f configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-r5k-cobalt - Header files for Linux r5k-cobalt configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-sb1-bcm91250a - Header files for Linux sb1-bcm91250a configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-2.6-sb1a-bcm91480b - Header files for Linux sb1a-bcm91480b configuration (dummy package)
linux-headers-4kc-malta - Header files for Linux 4kc-malta configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-5kc-malta - Header files for Linux 5kc-malta configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-loongson-2f - Header files for Linux loongson-2f configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-r5k-cobalt - Header files for Linux r5k-cobalt configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-sb1-bcm91250a - Header files for Linux sb1-bcm91250a configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-sb1a-bcm91480b - Header files for Linux sb1a-bcm91480b configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-4kc-malta - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-4kc-malta
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-5kc-malta - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-5kc-malta
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-all - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-all-mipsel - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-common - Common header files for Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-loongson-2e - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-loongson-2e
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-loongson-2f - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-loongson-2f
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-loongson-3 - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-loongson-3
linux-headers-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-sb1-bcm91250a - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-sb1-bcm91250a
linux-headers-loongson-2e - Header files for Linux loongson-2e configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-loongson-3 - Header files for Linux loongson-3 configuration (meta-package)  

uname -r
3.0.8-12453-gb3bae40
```

Comment: What does `apt-cache search linux-header` give, please? And please paste the output of `apt-cache policy` into your question.

Comment: Modified as requested, {uname -r}={3.0.8-12453-gb3bae40}

Comment: Strange, Ok, can you give `apt-cache policy linux-image...`? Where you can check for your linux-image for example by doing `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`.

Comment: **dpkg -l | grep linux-image** gives no output I'm affraid.

Comment: Did you install your linux kernel using a Debian binary package? If you didn't, then m-a etc won't work for you anyway. I strongly recommend you do so, unless you have good reason not to.

Comment: This kernel is distributed with imagination' s ci20 board. Do I need to compile my own kernel than or can make use of this source code somehow or is there another way or should I put it on ebay?

Comment: If you want to use one of the Debian kernels you can. Just install it and see if it boots. Are you saying the kernel you used came pre-installed? And if so, what is your pre-installed OS? You wrote above that it is  Debian wheezy, but if so, I would expect it to have a stock Debian kernel installed.

Comment: I'll try my luck with one of the stock Debian kernels. The kernel in use is part of the flashable image and it's ready-made for people like me who don't know what they're at. It is based on debian wheezy, with imagination's kernel. So my option's are to use one of the debian's kernels or compile my own than. Thanks for your interest in this tread mate.

Comment: I'd first check if your system is sufficiently Debian-like that it has Debian packages, otherwise you are wasting your time. Look at the output of `dpkg-l`, for example. It should show a long list of packages.